# Find equation of a circle that touches $2$ parallel lines and passes through $1$ point

Tags: circles

Lets say the circle touches $3x + 4y = 0$ and $3x + 4y -50 = 0$, and passes through the point $(2,1)$.

My approach was to let the centre of the circle be $(x,y)$, and set up $3$ equations:

$$\begin{align}&(2-x)^2 + (1-y)^2 = r^2\\&r = \frac{3x+4y}{\sqrt{25}}\\&r=\frac{3x+4y-50}{\sqrt{25}}\end{align}$$

where r is the radius. However the problem is when I consider the 2nd and 3rd equations, I would get $0 = -50$ which does not make sense.  Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: The radius is half the distance between the lines.

Comment: Also if you picture the setup, you can see that the centre of the circle lies on the line halfway between the two given lines, whose equation you should be able to get

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How did you dream up those equations for $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have a problem with the second and the third equations. The distance of a generic point $(x_0,y_0)$ from a line $ax+by+c=0$ is: $$d=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
There's an absolute value! So, if $(x_c,y_c)$ is the center of the circle, your equations should be:
$$\begin{align}&r = \frac{|3x_c+4y_c|}{\sqrt{25}}\\&r=\frac{|3x_c+4y_c-50|}{\sqrt{25}}\end{align}\:\Longrightarrow\:y_c=-\frac{3}{4}x_c+\frac{25}{4}$$
This implies that:
$$r=\frac{|3x_c+4y_c|}{5}=\frac{|3x_c+4\left(-\frac{3}{4}x_c+\frac{25}{4}\right)|}{5}=\frac{|3x_c-3x_c+25|}{5}=5$$
The $x$-coordinate $x_c$ of your center satisfies:
$$25=(2-x_c)^2+(1-y_c)^2$$
which can be simplified to: $$5x_c^2-38x_c+21=0\:\Longrightarrow\:x_c=\frac{3}{5},7$$
So there are two circles fulfilling your conditions:
$$\left(x-\frac{3}{5}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{29}{5}\right)^2=25,\quad\left(x-7\right)^2+\left(y-1\right)^2=25$$

**Further details:**
The equation $y_c=-\frac{3}{4}x_c+\frac{25}{4}$ can be derived straightforwardly. Since we know that the circle is tangent to the parallel lines $\ell_1:3x+4y=0$ and $\ell_2:3x+4y-50=0$, the center must lie on the line $\ell_3$ parallel to $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ such that $d(\ell_1,\ell_3)=d(\ell_2,\ell_3)$. This latter fact directly tells us that:
$$3x_c+4y_c-25=0$$ as wanted. Moreover, the radius is equal to:
$$r=d(\ell_1,\ell_3)=\frac{|0-25|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=5$$

Answer (score 0):

1. The distance between the 2 lines is given by $\pm {\dfrac {C_1 – C_2}{\sqrt {A^2 + B^2}}}$ = ... = 10.
2. The radius of the required circle is therefore = …. = 5.
3. Let X(h, k) be the center of the required circle (called Q). Note that X should lie on the line …. $L: 3x + 4y – 25 = 0$.
4. Let P = (2, 1). Then the QP = 5. Get the equation of the circle K (centered at P with radius = 5).
5. Solve L and K to get TWO sets of values for (h, k).
6. Use h, k , 5 to build the equations of the required circles.